# How to select maximum value from a subquery in SQL for a results display

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, display

I need to write a SQL query that displays a list of seven sellers – containing the top seller from each of the seven regions, who sold his/her German, American or Japanese car at the highest price for any German, American or Japanese car sold in his/her region in the year 2016.

For now, I managed to get the data that I need but I'm stuck when I need to only show results for each top seller in each of 7 regions.

Below is my code:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, category, car, region, selling_date, price
FROM
(SELECT first_name, last_name, cars.category, sellers.car, region, selling_date, price
FROM sellers
INNER JOIN regions ON sellers.region_id = regions.region_id
INNER JOIN cars ON sellers.car = cars.car
WHERE sellers.car = ANY (SELECT car FROM cars WHERE category = 'German' OR category ='American' OR category ='Japanese')
AND selling_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
) a 
WHERE price IN (SELECT TOP (7) MAX(price)FROM sellers GROUP BY region_id)
```

- problem is when I put "WHERE price IN (SELECT TOP (7) MAX(price)FROM sellers GROUP BY region_id)" it is taking max value from each region, only returns matching results.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL!?!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        first_name
    ,   last_name
    ,   cars.category
    ,   sellers.car
    ,   region
    ,   selling_date
    ,   price.price 
FROM        sellers 
INNER JOIN  regions ON  regions.region_id   =       sellers.region_id
INNER JOIN  cars    ON  cars.car            =       sellers.car
                    AND cars.category       IN      ('German', 'American', 'Japanese') 
                    AND cars.selling_date   BETWEEN ('2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31')
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      TOP 7 
                            seller_id                           --  asuming you have a seller_id.
                        ,   region_id                           --  if not, then go by region: delete prior line and change the ON Clause to region_id
                        ,   Price = MAX(price)
                FROM        sellers 
                GROUP BY    region_id, seller_id                -- delete seller_id if you dont have it
            )   price   ON  price.seller_id = seller.seller_id  --  change the ON Clause to region_id if no seller_id
```

Comment: Thank you Andy3B, but this returns an empty table. I have seller_id as well. I have 3 tables all together - sellers, cars, and regions.